# Deleting object completely after collision event in action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, instances

I have a basic game function that drops a ball every 500 milliseconds (with a timer event) and suppose to get rid of it when it hits a plate that drags after the mouse. The thing is; I tried to use the `deleteChild();` function, but it only removes the visual appearance of the ball object' without stopping its functionality, which causes a couple of problems:

1. The ball keeps going, and triggers an event of hitting the floor.
2. The dropBall(); function which animates the dropping ball, doesn't actually animate a new ball.

this is the complete script:

```
//imports:
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

//the function 'startGame, handles all basic game functions.
function startGame() {

//inisializes the variable 'Score' and gives it a value of 0.
var Score = 0;


//enter_frame listener. calls 'movePlate'
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlate);


//function 'movePlate'. makes the plate follow the mouse
function movePlate(event:Event):void {
    plate.x = mouseX;
}


//calls the dropBall function
dropBall()


//the function 'dropBall'. animates the droping ball
function dropBall() {
    var oldpost = 0;
    var randomNum:Number = Math.random() * 550;
    var xAxis:int = Math.round(randomNum);
    trace(randomNum);
    trace(xAxis);
    ball.x = xAxis;
    base.x = xAxis;
    var oldpost = xAxis;
    var ballTween:Tween = new Tween(ball, "y", null, 0, 500, 1.2, true); 
    oldpost = xAxis;
}

//function 'gameTime'. the timer function that controlls the intervals between falling eggs and ratio of good to bad eggs.
var gameTime1:Timer = new Timer(1000);
gameTime1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, gameTimer1Function)

function gameTimer1Function(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    dropBall();
}

gameTime1.start();

//enter frame event listener. calls  'checkCollision'
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkCollision);


//function checl collision. checks if the ball hits the plate
function checkCollision(event: Event):void {
    if(ball.hitTestObject(plate)) collisionDetected();
}


//function collision detected
function collisionDetected():void {
    Score ++;
    trace(Score);
    scoreText.text = Score;

}


//enter frame event listener. calls  'checkGameOver'.
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkGameOver);
 //function 'checkGameOver.
function checkGameOver(event: Event):void {
    if(ball.hitTestObject(floor)) gameOver();
}


//function 'gameOver'.
function gameOver():void {
    trace('GAME OVER!!! Your Score Is: ' + Score + '.');
    trace('Asta la Vista Baby :D');

}
}
startGame();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your'e code is not working as you explained. It is working like this:

You have only one ball, and it is beeing thorwn up, every second, refering to `gameTime1` tick calls dropBall (), which doing the following:

- it replaces the single ball you have to the 0 possition, and animating it withhin 1.2 seconds to the bottom. `var ballTween:Tween = new Tween(ball, "y", null, 0, 500, 1.2, true);`
- then the score++ is triggered independantly from the ball movement because it is on the enterframe event handler, and each frame the ball is hitting the plate the score increases
- YOU SHOULD REALLY LOOK INTO YOUR CODE AGAIN, and rething the architecture, how what and when it should work ( basicaly not only you need to know, what the software should do, but you need to explain this to the software.

**UPDATE:**

For how to export the movieclipt int oclass follow the tutorial:
http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/movieclips_classes_AS3_pg1.htm

Then  in your logics:

Function ( createBall )

- Create a instance of the ball. ( if you followed tutorial then you know how to )
- start the enterFrame which checks if the ball hitted the panel or the ground if it did stop the enterFrame event.
- After stop deside what to do depending on what was hitted

Should look like this:

```
if ( hitPanel )
{
    increaseScrore ()
}
if ( hitFloor )
{
    decreaseLive () 
}
```

- in each of those functions `increase...` and `decrease..` after they done everything should be `removeBall` function, and in `increase..` then a call to the `createBall` so everything is starting to repeat.

P.S. No offence please, but you can learn the programming language, in this case i see you know a bit, but if you are missing some logics, you will not find it on forums... Read some basics info about logics / architectures of the applications etc... and please take a look how the instances needed to be handeled.

P.S.S. Invest some to to know wtf is OOP. ;)

best wishes! Happy holidays :)

Comment: so how can I change it so it will make a new ball every time? And lets say it works like that, how do I make sure it will get rid of it?

Comment: now i changed the code so it will instantiate a new ball object every time the drop ball function goes off, but i still don't get how to check the collision, because right now the collision checking function makes errors. is it possible to check if an object that was instantiated from the library object 'ball1' hits the plate?

Comment: you should use only one global variable ball. which is defined outside of the functions. and each time you create a ball you creating `ballMC = new Ball (); addChild ( ballMC )`, and on removeBall function `removeChild ( ballMC ); ballMC = null`. And remember to stop all enterframe ticks, when you are removing the ball.

Comment: but on the collision detection, way should i put (like i have plate and i need the ball object)

Comment: what you had was quite good, but if you want more accurate look here: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the ball to `null` ?